# Как запускать/останавливать видео по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, видео

Указал ниже скрипт, который запускается при нажатии на кнопку. После этого видео останавливается, но при повторном нажатии не хочет запускаться. Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

```js
function PlayorStopVideo13() {
    const video = document.getElementById('rec_13');
    const btnSwitchVideo = document.getElementById('btnSwitchVideo-13');
    const textControl = document.getElementById('textControl');
    console.log(video);
    console.log(btnSwitchVideo);
    console.log(textControl);
    var IsVideoStart = '';

    if (IsVideoStart = true) {
        console.log('Остановить')
        video.pause();
        IsVideoStart = false;
        video.classList.add('video-paused'); // Добавили размытие на видео
        textControl.textContent = 'Воспроизвести видео';
    } if (IsVideoStart = false) {
        console.log('Запустить видео')
        video.play();
        video.classList.remove('video-paused'); // Убираем размытие на видео
        textControl.textContent = 'Остановить видео';
    } else {
        console.log('Ошибка');
    }


};
```

Comment: `if (IsVideoStart = true) ` - это присвоение ,а не сравнение, нужно `===`

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу таким образом:

```js
function PlayorStopVideo13() {
    const video = document.getElementById('rec_13');
    const btnSwitchVideo = document.getElementById('btnSwitchVideo-13');
    const textControl = document.getElementById('textControl');

    if (video.classList.contains("video-paused")) {
        video.play();
        video.classList.remove('video-paused');
        textControl.textContent = 'Воспроизвести видео';
    } else {
        video.pause();
        video.classList.add('video-paused');
        textControl.textContent = 'Остановить видео';
    };
};
```